# unexpected cast to ViewGroup: layout tag was RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I am doing the "Create the Second Activity" tutorial on this [page](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)
I have done everything carefully and I am getting an error. I don't understand why there is an error, especially as I'm simply copy/pasting the code they tell me to copy/paste!

The following line of code:

```
ViewGroup layout = (VeiwGroup)  findViewById(R.id.activity_display_message);
```

gives me this error:

> `unexpected cast to ViewGroup: layout tag was RelativeLayout.`

Well, I don't know what that's talking about.  I know the xml file is a relative layout. But I don't know why that's a problem or where the problem really is.

Comment: You also need to post the relevant code. `activity_display_message` is the id of relativelayout!.

Comment: We need to see your XML. I followed the tutorial for how I understand what it is asking. Cannot reproduce

Answer (score 0):

Change your `ViewGroup` to `RelativeLayout`

When you call the ViewGroup class you are missing some of the method of the RelativeLayout method as ViewGroup is a parent class and Relative layout is just advanced version of it with some other class Here is the difference between both the class

```
@RemoteView
public class RelativeLayout extends ViewGroup {
public static final int ABOVE = 2;
public static final int ALIGN_BASELINE = 4;
public static final int ALIGN_BOTTOM = 8;
public static final int ALIGN_END = 19;
public static final int ALIGN_LEFT = 5;
public static final int ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM = 12;
public static final int ALIGN_PARENT_END = 21;
public static final int ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT = 9;
public static final int ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT = 11;
public static final int ALIGN_PARENT_START = 20;
public static final int ALIGN_PARENT_TOP = 10;
public static final int ALIGN_RIGHT = 7;
public static final int ALIGN_START = 18;
public static final int ALIGN_TOP = 6;
public static final int BELOW = 3;
public static final int CENTER_HORIZONTAL = 14;
public static final int CENTER_IN_PARENT = 13;
public static final int CENTER_VERTICAL = 15;
public static final int END_OF = 17;
public static final int LEFT_OF = 0;
public static final int RIGHT_OF = 1;
public static final int START_OF = 16;
public static final int TRUE = -1;

public RelativeLayout(Context context) {
    super((Context)null, (AttributeSet)null, 0, 0);
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public RelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super((Context)null, (AttributeSet)null, 0, 0);
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public RelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super((Context)null, (AttributeSet)null, 0, 0);
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public RelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super((Context)null, (AttributeSet)null, 0, 0);
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public boolean shouldDelayChildPressedState() {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public void setIgnoreGravity(int viewId) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public int getGravity() {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public void setGravity(int gravity) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public void setHorizontalGravity(int horizontalGravity) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public void setVerticalGravity(int verticalGravity) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public int getBaseline() {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public void requestLayout() {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public RelativeLayout.LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(AttributeSet attrs) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

protected android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams() {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

protected boolean checkLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams p) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

protected android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public CharSequence getAccessibilityClassName() {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public static class LayoutParams extends MarginLayoutParams {
    @ExportedProperty(
        category = "layout"
    )
    public boolean alignWithParent;

    public LayoutParams(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super((android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)null);
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public LayoutParams(int w, int h) {
        super((android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)null);
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams source) {
        super((android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)null);
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public LayoutParams(MarginLayoutParams source) {
        super((android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)null);
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams source) {
        super((android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)null);
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public String debug(String output) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public void addRule(int verb) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public void addRule(int verb, int subject) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public void removeRule(int verb) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public int getRule(int verb) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public int[] getRules() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public void resolveLayoutDirection(int layoutDirection) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }
}
}
```

[ViewGroup class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html)

You can see that you are not calling some of the method required for the relativelayout .Thats the reason you are gettinng error.

Answer (score -1):

In article (link you given) you can find note:

> Note: The XML layout generated by previous versions of Android Studio
>   might not include the android:id attribute. The call findViewById()
>   will fail if the layout does not have the android:id attribute. If
>   this is the case, open activity_display_message.xml and add the
>   attribute android:id="@+id/activity_display_message" to the layout
>   element.

Add missing attribute and error should be gone.

Comment: While you might be correct, it would assign `layout` to null if this were true.